# How many Young diagrams with length of at most $p$ rows and $q$ columns

Tags: integer-partitions

How many Young diagrams are there with length of at most $p$ rows and $q$ columns, without restrictions on the weight of the diagrams?

The previous 2 questions asked for

1. Total number of Young diagrams with weight 6 and
2. Total number of Young diagrams with weight 7, excluding diagrams with more than 3 rows.

The answers I got are 1) 11 and 2) 8,

By counting the number of partitions of the integers 6 and 7 respectively, and subtracting $7, 6+1, 5+2, 5+1+1, 4+3, 4+2+1, 4+1+1+1$ from all partitions of 7.

However, I have no idea how to do that with unspecified weight, and taking into account the question details.

**Notice the question is talking about Young diagrams, as opposed to Young tableaux.**

Comment: I think in effect you want the number of solutions to $0 \le x_1\le x_2\le \cdots \le x_p \le q$.  It might be worth adding something to each to make them distinct, at which point this becomes easy

Comment: @Henry how do I set everything up?

Comment: An even easier approach would say you want a path from one corner of the $p\times q$ rectangle to the opposite corner to separate your Young diagram from the rest of the rectangle

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to post a complete answer in case someone finds this question later.  This follows up on Henry's comment of 15 January.

First, judging from your answer to #2, it looks like you're visualizing partitions in the "French" convention, with $4+2+1$ consisting of three columns with heights 4, 2, 1 from left to right.  (The other option is "English" where $4+2+1$ corresponds to three rows with lengths 4, 2, 1 from top to bottom.)  The enumerations don't depend on this choice, of course, but I wanted to answer your question in the appropriate context.

A partition with at most $p$ rows and at most $q$ columns is determined by a path starting at $(0,p)$ and ending at $(q,0)$ consisting of $p$ steps down and $q$ steps right.  One extreme case is $q$ rights followed by $p$ downs, giving the partition $p+\cdots+p$ repeated $q$ times of weight $pq$.  The other extreme case is $p$ downs followed by $q$ rights, the empty partition of 0.  Supposing $p$ and $q$ are large enough, the path given by $p-4$ downs, right, down, down, right, down, right, down, $q-3$ rights describes $4+2+1$.

The number of such paths is the binomial coefficient $\binom{p+q}{p}$ since it is enough to specify the positions of the $p$ down steps among the $p+q$ total steps.  (Generally, questions about a specific weight are harder.)